# What does the entity framework do with locking sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework

I'm not a real database expert, and i was wondering if you could tell me what kind of lock Sql server uses in combination with the entity framework in the following cases:

I read 40 records from a table, update them in code and call SaveChanges to the context

I read 1 record from a table, update it in code and call SaveChanges to the context

I create 1 new record (object) in code and call SaveChanges to the context

I create 40 new records (object) in code and call SaveChanges to the context

I also wondered, is it somehow possible to see which locks are used (set?) by Sql Server?

Michel

Comment: I think the better question would be to ask how you could profile this yourself....

Comment: hm, agree, sounds lazy but if someone already knows it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locking depends on how you have SQL Server configured, not on the EF. [You monitor locking using the dynamic management views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx).

Comment: oh, ok. I thought that EF maybe would pass some locking hint or demand to Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is difficult to answer, because it all depends on how you write the code. Entity framework doesn't do the actual SELECT-statement before you use any data.
For instance:
Dim v = (From a in Something Select a)
For Each b in v
Next

In this code block, the actual "SELECT * FROM Something" isn't executed on the SQL Server before it comes to the "For Each" line.
The best answer I can give you is to test it yourself by looking at sys.dm_tran_locks which returns all locks.